# Vertical-align:middle and display:table issue?

Tags: html, css

So I have user `display:table` for `nav`, `display:table-row` for `nav ul`, `display:table-cell` and `vertical-align:middle` for `nav ul li`. The menu items still won't align in the middle vertically. Can anyone help?

```css
#main_nav {
  display: table;
}
    
#main_nav ul {
  display: table-row;
}

#main_nav ul li {
  padding: 10px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<nav id="main_nav">
   <ul>
       <li><a href="index.html">Blog</a></li>
       <li><a href="video_screencasts.html">Videos</a></li>
       <li><a href="almanac.html">Almanac</a></li>
       <li><a href="snippets.html">Snippets</a></li>
       <li><a href="forums.html">Forums</a></li>
       <li><a href="shop.html">Shop</a></li>
       <li><a href="lodge.html">Lodge</a></li>
       <li><a href="jobs.html">Jobs</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: already working i guess, could you please post a working fiddle/snippet?

Comment: Looks OK here ([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/at5mjbb2/)), but the question really is, vertically aligned to _what_?

Answer (score 0):

From your statement **The menu items still won't align in the middle vertically.**
I presume that you want the table to be in the centre of the page.

The code you have used, `vertical-align:middle;` is not the same.
Check out [vertical-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) or this [CSS vertical-align Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp)
Its very neatly explained with working examples.

In order to align in the centre of the page you can run the css as below

```
.wrapper {
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper ul {
  display: table-row;
}

.wrapper ul li {
  padding: 10px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Here is the [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7kdxqtpe/)

Or Very simply and easily you could replace the whole code with

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<table align="center">
  
<tr><td><a href="index.html">Blog</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="video_screencasts.html">Videos</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="almanac.html">Almanac</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="snippets.html">Snippets</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="forums.html">Forums</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="shop.html">Shop</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="lodge.html">Lodge</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="jobs.html">Jobs</a></td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, but the bottom one won't validate. Using CSS margins is better.